# How to catch @ngrx/effects errors properly?

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I know this question has been asked several times, but keep in mind my specific issue, because I couldn't find anything that solves it properly.

I have an `effect` that should perform multiple HTTP requests in a specific order - call 1, call 2, call 3. I want to be able to catch *any error* that is being thrown throughout the chain. I want to keep the structure of the `rxjs` operators as flat as possible to avoid nested spaghetti code.

Here's sample code:

```
getMockDataEffect$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ApiGetMockData),
      concatMap(() => {
        return this.mockApi.mock1().pipe(
          concatMap(() => {
            return this.mockApi.mock2();
          }),
          concatMap(() => {
            return this.mockApi.mock3();
          }),
          map(res => ApiSuccess({ data: res })),
          catchError(error => of(ApiError({ error }))),
        )
      }
      )
    )
  )
```

In the example given above, if an error occurs in `mock2` or `mock3`, it would be successfully caught. However, if one occurs in `mock1`, the error won't be caught at all.

My question is: how do I structure my effect in such a way that my `catchError` operator would catch any error occurring in `mock1`, `mock2` or `mock3`, *without completing the effect's observable*? Meaning, if an error occurs, I should be able to dispatch the action and run the effect successfully after that.

Here's a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-effects-example-kqtjop).

Answer (score 2):

I think your example is good.

The issue is the `throw` because I think this is for JavaScript execution and it just stops because it is not being caught.

A realistic scenario would be that the functions return an error in an Observable format and for this you have to use `throwError`. When an http request fails, it will be an error observable.

So to get your situation working, change `mockapi.service.ts` to the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MockApiService {

  mock1() {
    //return throwError('e1');
    return of('mock1');
  }

  mock2() {
    // return throwError('e2');
    return of('mock2');
  }

  mock3() {
    // return throwError('e3');
    return of('mock3');
  }
}
```

Uncomment any of the `throwError`s on whatever function to simulate it has errored.